# Twilight Zone (TOS) Visual Riddle #7

Tags: visual, rebus

Once again... you know the drill.

[image]

Comment: If it's okay for you, can you please link to the first part for those new?

Comment: Hi JoeB, just a little advice (yes I know you haven't asked!): I'd be wary of flooding the site with all these rebuses at once - people will likely lose interest pretty fast and you may see not just a fall in upvotes but also a decline in the quality of your puzzles as you attempt to rush the next one out. Take your time, don't release them all so soon after each other (it's a pretty niche subject area - a glut might alienate many members of this truly global community), and overall you might find the experience even more rewarding :) I hope you're enjoying making them. Happy puzzling!

Comment: Another way is to write a single post consisting all $7$ rebuses. Sometimes they are better together especially if they are sharing a same theme and relatively small!

Comment: Thanks for all the above comments. I'm new to Stack Exchange and still figuring it all out...

Comment: No worries. Everybody's new at some point - we've all been there :) Thanks for engaging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it’s

> [Jack Klugman](https://twilightzone.fandom.com/wiki/Jack_Klugman), from Jack + Plug + Man.

Comment: Correct, El-Guest!

Comment: If answers are correct — including on all of your previous questions — please feel free to mark them as accepted! This signals to the community that the questions have a solution you agree with. Thanks, @JoeB!